# How to check that cache is working on current page?

Tags: caching

Some modules silently turn off caching on certain pages. How is the easiest way to check that this is the case and also identify problematic module?

Comment: With Boost cache it's simple, there is a html comment at the bottom of the page. with other caches it's a bit more interesting.

Comment: @Mołot I'm primarily interested in standard Drupal cache, but instructions to other caches are also appreciate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to inspect the HTTP response headers.

For example, with your browser DOM inspector tool ( e.g [Chrome's "Network" tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_headers) )

**Cache Miss**

Here's some sample response headers from drupal.org showing a cache miss. In this case, using Varnish however core Drupal cache also sets similar headers.

[image: cache miss http header]

**Cache Hit**

Here's one showing a standard Drupal cache hit:

[image: cache hit http header]

Comment: But Drupal.org is behind Varnish, isn't it? I can't see X-Cache headers on my Drupal accessed directly. Or I would if the page I'm testing it with was cacheable?

Comment: @Mołot I can see the Varnish headers if I'm logged out.

Comment: For my Drupal 7 site I indeed see header `X-Drupal-Cache: HIT` but on my Drupal 6 site I don't see anything. It could be stripped by reverse proxy?

Comment: @user11153 yes, D6 doesn't appear to set the X-Drupal-Cache HTTP header there. However D7 does so in `_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache`

Comment: @DavidThomas So what check cache status in Drupal 6? Are there any alternatives? And thanks for instructions to D7.

Comment: OK, I think that I found the solution for Drupal 6 also.

Answer (score 0):

### Adding cache headers to Drupal 6 default cache

Sadly, it's involving some core hacking.

In file `includes/bootstrap.inc` change lines from

```
      // If there is a cached page, display it.
      if ($cache) {
        drupal_page_cache_header($cache);
        // If the skipping of the bootstrap hooks is not enforced, call hook_exit.
        if ($cache_mode != CACHE_AGGRESSIVE) {
          bootstrap_invoke_all('exit');
        }
        // We are done.
        exit;
      }
      // Prepare for non-cached page workflow.
      drupal_page_header();
      break;
```

to

```
      // If there is a cached page, display it.
      if ($cache) {
        header('X-Drupal-Cache: HIT');
        drupal_page_cache_header($cache);
        // If the skipping of the bootstrap hooks is not enforced, call hook_exit.
        if ($cache_mode != CACHE_AGGRESSIVE) {
          bootstrap_invoke_all('exit');
        }
        // We are done.
        exit;
      }
      // Prepare for non-cached page workflow.
      header('X-Drupal-Cache: MISS');
      drupal_page_header();
      break;
```

and the rest of instructions it's exactly as [in David's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87189/11153).