# Why cache form table gets new entries by anon page views?

Tags: forms, caching

I am seeing new entries in my cache_form table when anonymous user view a page that had a comment form. The page cache is enabled and set to 30 min. Does this mean that cache page is being bypassed? Or does drupal cahe forms for every anonymous user using a hashed key?

Also I should mention that this happening for forms called and renderd in the theme layer (someone's mistake and I'm trying to correct this) .

Answer (score 1):

Comment form is a form. All forms generate entries in form cache. Form engine uses cache as it's temporary data storage, not as the cache in usual definition of the word.

One thing it always store is a list of fields it actually displayed to a client, so it can compare it with a list of values that come back and prevent hijacking and other abuse - hence one entry per user session per form.

Comment: But I thought cache page has the full page? Does this mean cache page is not serving the page?

Comment: @arsenelupin If there is a form on it? Nope, no luck here. See [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/87184/16495) to know how to test it yourself.

Comment: But this cannot be true. https://drupal.org/ has a search form on it and when visiting it you get a cache hit `X-Cache:HIT`. And I did a test on a fresh install it looks like I get a cache hit even when there is a comment form for anon user. I think the issue I am seeing is isolated for one use case as a result of bad implementation.

Comment: @arsenelupin as far as I understand search form is a bit different case, that goes around caching for performance. The fact that there is a comment is irrelevant, and whenever I see a commenf **form** on drupal.org, I get `X-Cache:MISS` as predicted.

Comment: came back to this recently and installed vanilla standard drupal, enebaled anon comments and enabled cache. The comment form does NOT add entries into the cache form table on each request and the page cache does NOT break except when a comment is posted. http://i.imgur.com/W7ftpIu.png
I am still puzzled.

Comment: I also tried the form_example module and they don't add entered into cache_form table. Saw this and so far this makes the most sense https://www.drupal.org/node/2819375.